# How to disable Firefox Live Bookmarks

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, rss

Before this, RSS pages were displayed in the browser window with a nice formatting as a content.

On an RSS page, I accidentally checked `Always use Live Bookmarks to subscribe to podcasts.` and then the `Subscribe Now` button. *(Note that I have a non-default dark theme in Firefox, but this is still just native Firefox.)*

[image: RSS before]

***Now every time I visit the RSS page, the content is `not` displayed***, and all I get is a dialog titled `Subscribe with Live Bookmarks`.

[image: RSS after]

I searched on the Internet, and I found that I should go to the *Tools* menu (in <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>), select *Options*, then on the *Applications* tab I should filter to *Web Feeds* and set it to *Preview in Firefox*.

[image: Options1]

Now here is my **problem**. **I still only get the dialog** titled *"Subscribe with Live Bookmarks"*. I've tried to disable all Add-ons from the *Help* menu and start Firefox in safe mode, but it didn't help. I've even tried to delete the live bookmark I added, but it didn't help neither.

My Firefox version is 17.0.1, I'm running on Windows XP pro SP3 32-bit, my user is *administrator*, I have all rights in the Mozilla folder in Appdata, and I have more GB free disk space.

**What should I do to make Firefox display the RSS pages again as content, instead of bookmarking?**

Answer (score 2):

I found out that in the *about:config* page (URL/address), if I write "feeds" to the filter, I get several pages that are not on their *default* settings, but *user set*.

[image: About settings]

I reset them all by right clicking them and selecting *Reset* **all of them**.

[image: Reset]

**Now it works!** Firefox is **displaying RSS pages as content again!**

---

Fellow users or user experience designers may find my detailed struggle useful.

The setting names make it evident that not all RSS go by the name "Web feeds". I probably "should have realized" in the first place that they are called podcasts (as they are that), but, to me, these were always just RSS pages.

I went instead to menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Applications* again, and wrote "feeds" to the search box. But I got only "Web Feeds". (I've also tried "audio", no luck). I searched then for any entry with an "RSS icon". That's how I realized that "**Podcast**" and "**Video Podcast**" is where it must be set, if you use the UI.

[image: The right place]